# Android MediaPlayer : IllegalStateException when app closes/press back button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

Im streaming an mp3 audio from a url by using mediaplayer, Now im able to play music , But when **i press back button or close the app, it crashes.**
can anyone pls help me to find my mistake. 
thank you.

*My code is :*

```
        private ImageView play, forward, backward;
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private boolean playing = false;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        private String mp3link;
        private SeekBar seekbar;
        private Handler handler = new Handler();
        private int mediaPos;
        private int mediaMax;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final String url ="";
            initWidgets();

        }

    private void initWidgets() {
        mp3link = "http://loc8app.com/church/uploads/audio/749928ad6fcb7b1aceefdf03bd7a9465.mp3";
        play = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
//        forward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playeer_forward);
//        backward = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playeer_back);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playFunction();
            }
        });

        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void playFunction() {
        if (!playing) {
            try {
                dialog = ProgressDialog
                        .show(MainActivity.this,
                                "",
                                getString(com.root5solutions.music.R.string.buffering),
                                true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mp3link);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                        playing = true;
                        //this is new
                        mediaPos = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        mediaMax = mp.getDuration();

                        seekbar.setMax(mediaMax);
                        seekbar.setProgress(mediaPos);
                        //this line is the error
                        handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
                        handler.postDelayed(moveSeekBarThread, 100);

                        mp.start();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        } else {
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            playing = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    private Runnable moveSeekBarThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                seekbar.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                seekbar.setProgress(mediaPos_new);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // Looping the thread after 1 second

            }

        }
    };
}
```

*Logcat shows :*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.root.music, PID: 26981
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                              at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.root.music.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:132)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

Comment: Where is your `isPlaying()` method?

Comment: Looks to me like your `Runnable` is firing after you've called `mediaPlayer.release()`. Does the issue still manifest if you call `handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);` before you call `mediaPlayer.release()` in `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: `if (mediaPlayer!= null){
          if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
              mediaPlayer.stop();
          mediaPlayer.release();
      }

     super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: thanks clownba0t . It worked and not crashing now. it was the problem of the runnable as u said . Can u pls post it as an answer pls ?

Comment: @clownba0t Well describe. post as answer .

Comment: @clownba0t: why did u downvoted other 2 answers, those are also helpful informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be being caused by the `moveSeekBarThread` `Runnable`, from which the exception is being raised, continuing to execute after `mediaPlayer` is released in `onBackPressed()`. This results in the the `isPlaying()` method being executed, which as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()) will result in an `IllegalStateException`:

> if the internal player engine has not been initialized or has been released.

Looking at `moveSeekBarThread`, it seems to be configured to reschedule itself endlessly by posting itself back into the `handler` `Handler` instance with a delay. This process is not being stopped when the user leaves the activity, which explains why `moveSeekBarThread` keeps running. So, based on the above, one solution could be to make sure that any instances of `moveSeekBarThread` in `handler`'s queue are removed before calling `mediaPlayer.release()` when the user leaves the activity.

You should be able to do that by calling `handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);` before you call `mediaPlayer.release()`. For example, as follows:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

It should be okay to call it right before `mediaPlayer.release()`, but I  think it's safer to call it regardless of whether `mediaPlayer` is playing. This way, if the `Runnable` does get or remain started somehow despite the media player not having being started or having been stopped, the `Runnable` will still be cleared.

As an aside, while I don't have any experience with `MediaPlayer`, I happened to notice that the documentation of the [`release`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) method has the following to say:

> It is considered good practice to call this method when you're done using the MediaPlayer. In particular, whenever an Activity of an application is paused (its onPause() method is called), or stopped (its onStop() method is called), this method should be invoked to release the MediaPlayer object, unless the application has a special need to keep the object around. In addition to unnecessary resources (such as memory and instances of codecs) being held, failure to call this method immediately if a MediaPlayer object is no longer needed may also lead to continuous battery consumption for mobile devices, and playback failure for other applications if no multiple instances of the same codec are supported on a device.

So unless there is that special need to keep the media player around in the activity in your case, it might be better to handle the release process (including clearing `moveSeekBarThread` from `handler`) in `onPause` or `onStop` instead.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you are getting **[IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)** .

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate
>   time .

Call `super.onBackPressed();` after **if** condition

```
 @Override 
public void onBackPressed() 
 {
      if (mediaPlayer!= null)
     {
             if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
              mediaPlayer.stop();
              mediaPlayer.release();
      }

     super.onBackPressed(); // Call here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what **illegalStateException** means:

According to Android docs:

> It Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

have a look at the state diagram of a media player:

https://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif

Calling setDataSource(FileDescriptor), or setDataSource(String), or setDataSource(Context, Uri), or setDataSource(FileDescriptor, long, long), or setDataSource(MediaDataSource) transfers a MediaPlayer object in the Idle state to the Initialized state.
An IllegalStateException is thrown if setDataSource() is called in any other state.

It is good programming practice to always look out for IllegalArgumentException and IOException that may be thrown from the overloaded setDataSource methods.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is quite correct. The meat of the implementation of `onBackPressed`, at least in `Activity` on API 24, seems to schedule the `Activity` instance to be finished. So, the code after the call to super will still be run before the `Activity` is finished, meaning the media player will still be stopped and released. The root cause of the issue the OP is facing seems to be that a `Runnable` is touching the media player after it has been released, which is a different issue. I don't think that changing the location of the call to `super` will resolve the issue in this case.